# Возможно ли объединить два разных блока в один при просмотре на мобильном устройстве?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, адаптивная-верстка

Всем здравствуйте! Адаптивный дизайн сайта. Два совершенно отдельных блока каждый со своим меню: один блок с главным меню в шапке, другой блок с дополнительным меню в сайдбаре. Возможно ли их в принципе объединить в один при просмотре на мобильном устройстве? Конечно, наверное глупый вопрос, но такая задача у меня стоит, а значит может быть и возможно сделать невозможное? Подскажите, пожалуйста, реально ли? Благодарю!

Comment: Зачем их объединять, если можно сделать скрытый на десктопе блок, какой надо - уже объединенный и показывать его на устройствах, скрывая те 2?

Comment: На css нет. На JS без проблем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну конечно вопрос из вакуума ... как люблю повторять "возможно все" ... на вскидку при нужных параметрах устройства клонируешь оба блока, вставляешь в общий контейнер и вставляешь куда тебе нужно ... нужно больше информации, ибо решений у этой задачи с десяток может набраться

Comment: речь не шла про дублирование блоков, можно клонировать с сохранением всего функционала, вставить куда надо, удалить "прототип". Ну и в обратном порядке, иначе вариантов нет, ибо если блоки разнесены в разные концы разметки, то соединить их не повредив контекст можно только выпилив их из конекста (фиксированым или абсолютным позиционированием). Зависит от задачи, но ещё раз повторюсь, нерешаемых проблем нет, "не мытьем - так катанием" решается все ....

Comment: var mobileContainer = $('container');
var block = $('block');
var clone = block.clone(true);

mobileContainer.append(clone);
block.remove();

Ну или типа того